# How to force page margin using expex?

Tags: expex

I use expex package to create bilingual book. On some pages (usually even) layouts breaks. There is not enough margin on right side. The question is why?

I am going to post some long example with demo to illustrate the problem.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}

\title{Le petit prince}
\author{Antoine de Saint-Exupéry}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lingset{glspace=1em,everygla={\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}},everyglb=\pdfliteral{0.25 g 0.25 G} \scriptsize, glhangstyle=none, glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}

\begingl
\gla
{J’ai ainsi vécu} seul, sans personne avec qui parler véritablement, {jusqu’à} {une panne} {dans le désert du Sahara}, {il y a six ans}. 
{Quelque chose} s’était cassé dans mon moteur. 
{Et comme} {je n’avais} avec moi ni mécanicien, ni passagers, {je me préparai} à {essayer de réussir}, {tout seul}, {une réparation difficile}. 
{C’était} pour moi {une question de vie ou de mort}. 
{J’avais} {à peine} {de l’eau à boire} pour huit jours.//
\glb
{Żyłem zatem} samemu, bez osoby z którą {rozmawia się} wiarygodnie {aż do} awarii {na pustyni Sahara} {6 lat temu} 
Coś było zepsute w moim silniku
{I jako że} {nie miałem} ze sobą ani mechanika ani pasażerów {przygotowałem się} do {spróbowania} samemu {ciężkiej naprawy}
{To była} dla mnie {kwestia życia i śmierci}
Miałem {zaledwie} {wody do picia} na osiem dni//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
{Le premier} soir {je me suis donc endormi} sur {le sable} {à mille milles} {de toute terre habitée}.
J’étais {bien plus} isolé qu’un naufragé sur {un radeau} au milieu {de l’océan}. 
Alors {vous imaginez} ma surprise, {au lever du jour}, quand {une drôle de petite voix} {m’a réveillé}. Elle {disait :…}//
\glb
Pierwszego wieczoru {zatem zasnąłem} na piasku {tysiące mil} {od ziemii zamieszkałej}
Byłem {dużo bardziej} odizolowony niż rozbitek na tratwie po środku oceanu
Więc {wyobrażacie sobie} moje zaskoczenie {o świcie} kiedy {zabawny głosik} {mnie obudził}.
On mówił//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— {S’il vous plaît…} dessine-moi {un mouton !} //
\glb
{} Proszę {narysuj mi} baranka//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— {Hein !} //
\glb
{} Co//
\endgl


\begingl
\gla
— Dessine-moi {un mouton}…//
\glb
{} {Narysuj mi} baranka//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
{J’ai sauté sur mes pieds} {comme si} {j’avais été} frappé par {la foudre}. 
{J’ai bien frotté} mes yeux. 
{J’ai bien regardé}. 
Et {j’ai vu} {un petit bonhomme} {tout à fait} extraordinaire qui {me considérait} gravement. 
Voilà {le meilleur} portrait que, {plus tard}, {j’ai réussi à faire de lui}.//
\glb
{Skoczyłem na równe nogi} jakbym był trafionym przez piorun
Przetarłem moje oczy. 
{Dobrze się przyjrzałem}. 
I widziałem {małego gościa} zupełnie nadzwyczajnego który {przyglądał mi się} poważnie 
Oto najlepszy portret który później {udało mi się jemu zrobić}//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
Mais mon dessin, {bien sûr}, est beaucoup moins ravissant que {le modèle}. 
Ce {n’est pas de ma faute}. 
{J’avais été} découragé dans ma carrière {de peintre} par {les grandes personnes}, {à l’âge de six ans}, et {je n’avais rien appris} {à dessiner}, sauf {les boas} fermés et {les boas} ouverts.//
\glb
Ale mój rysunek oczywiście jest dużo mniej wspaniały niż model
To {nie jest moja wina}
Byłem zniechęcony w mojej karierze malarza przez {dorosłe osoby} {w wieku 6 lat} i {nie nauczyłem się nic} rysować poza boza zamkniętymi i boa otwartymi//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
{Je regardai} donc cette apparition avec {des yeux} tout {ronds d’étonnement}.
{N’oubliez pas} que {je me trouvais} {à mille milles} {de toute région habitée}. 
Or mon petit bonhomme {ne me semblait} ni égaré, ni {mort de fatigue}, ni {mort de faim}, ni {mort de soif}, ni {mort de peur}. 
Il {n’avait} {en rien} l’apparence {d’un enfant} perdu {au milieu} {du désert}, {à mille milles} {de toute région habitée}. 
Quand {je réussis} enfin {à parler}, {je lui dis :}//
\glb
{Przyglądałem się} zatem tej zjawie z oczami całymi {zaokrąglonymi ze zdziwienia}
{Nie zapomnijcie} że {znalazłem się} {tysiące mil} {od regionu zamieszkałych}
Otóż mój mały gość {nie wydawał się} ani zgubiony ani zmęczony ani wygłodzony ani spragniony ani przestraszony.
On {nie miał} {w ogóle} wyglądu dziecka zgubionego {po środku} pustyni {tysiące mil} {od regionu zamieszkałego}
Kiedy {udało mi się} wreszcie odezwać, {powiedziałem mu}//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— Mais {qu’est-ce que} tu fais là//
\glb
{} Ale {co} ty robisz tutaj//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
Et {il me répéta} alors, {tout doucement}, comme {une chose} très {sérieuse :}//
\glb
I {powtórzył mi} wówczas powoli jakby rzecz bardzo ważną//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— {S’il vous plaît…} dessine-moi {un mouton…}//
\glb
{} Proszę {narysuj mi} baranka//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
Quand {le mystère} est trop impressionnant, {on n’ose pas désobéir}. 
Aussi absurde que cela {me semblât} {à mille milles} {de tous} {les endroits habités} et {en danger de mort}, {je sortis} {de ma poche} {une feuille de papier} et {un stylographe}. 
Mais {je me rappelai} {alors que} {j’avais surtout étudié} {la géographie}, l’histoire, {le calcul} et {la grammaire} et {je dis} {au petit bonhomme} (avec {un peu} {de mauvaise humeur}) que {je ne savais pas} dessiner. 
Il me {répondit :}//
\glb
Kiedy tajemnica jest zbyt imponująca {nie można odważyć się sprzeciwić} 
Również absurdalnie że tutaj {mnie wydawało się} {tysiące mil} {od wszystkich} {miejsc zamieszkałych} i {w niebezpieczeństwie śmierci} wyjąłem {z kieszieni} {kartkę papieru} i {wieczne pióro}
Ale {przypominałem sobie} {w tym samym momencie że} {studiowałem głównie} geografię, historię, rachunkowość i gramatykę i powiedziałem {małemu gościowi} (z trochę {złym humorem}) że {nie umiem} rysować
On mi odpowiedział//
\(\)\endgl


\end{document}
```

Demo: http://helid.vipower.pl/demo.pdf

How can I force latex to keep appropriate margin?

Comment: I don't know the package so it's hard for me to correct but it will be difficult to linebreak the French texts without french hyphenation, and I don't see french language specified anywhere

Comment: I've tried `\usepackage[francais, french, polish]{babel}` without desired effect. By the way are `french` and `francais` the same package?

Comment: I think the babel options are the same., yes, but looking at your document is there any automatic linebreaking? It looks like each `\gla` is forced to a line so the commentry can line up under each word. If that is the case you need to put less words on a line, or use a smaller font

Comment: Probably it is. However, I would like to create bilingual book. If I would make one sentence smaller there will be next sentence and so on. I would have to manually create one sentence per each line. It doesn't sound like elegant solution.

Comment: I have never used the package, so don't despair, probably you'll get an answer from someone who does know its features better:-)

Comment: Are you sure that `expex` is appropriate for this? I don't know the package but the blurb suggests that it is designed for typesetting linguistic examples etc. which would typically, I assume, be rather shorter than an entire book. There are packages, on the other hand, designed for typesetting things like critical editions, parallel texts etc. which might possibly be more suitable?

Comment: @cfr I do not know any alternative to expex. Could you give me some example?

Comment: @estshy: The comment by cfr is crucial! I have used the package so far, but `parallel` is designed for typesetting texts in parallel, i.e. side-by-side translations of texts

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I rather would like to create interlinear translation not parallel. It's completely different idea, but thanks for advice.

Comment: It just doesn't at all seem to be intended for this and usually things don't work out nicely when you try to use a potato masher to make sponge cake. At least look at http://ctan.org/topic/crit-ed - not all of the packages are for parallel texts. I assume that `expex` is blocking hyphenation? At least, there's nothing which tells it which hyphenation patterns to use. (Not sure why you have loaded `babel` with American English rather than French.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parameters provided by `expex` can be manipulated to fix this problem:

1. `glspace`: controls the horizontal space between `glwords`
2. `glrightskip`: controls how much horizontal space there can be between the right edge of the last `glword` and the right margin

These are described in section 9.1 of the [`expex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf), and section 11.3.1 is specifically about how to set them so that your lines will wrap correctly.

In your case, you have a very narrow page width and some very long `glwords` like *nie można odważyć się sprzeciwić*. `expex` cannot break lines at spaces within `glwords`, let alone hyphenate within them, so you need to increase `glspace` and `glrightskip` to make sure these long `glwords` don't extend into the right margin.

I've modified your MWE to use a value of `!0pt plus .2em` for `glspace` and `0pt plus .3\hsize` for `glrightskip`. You may want to play with these a little to get it to look exactly as you want it, but these values do prevent each line in the MWE from extending into the right margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper, titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage{showframe} % used to show margin lines

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}

\title{Le petit prince}
\author{Antoine de Saint-Exupéry}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lingset{glspace=!0pt plus .2em, glrightskip=0pt plus .3\hsize, everygla={\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}},everyglb=\pdfliteral{0.25 g 0.25 G} \scriptsize, glhangstyle=none, glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}

\begingl
\gla
{J’ai ainsi vécu} seul, sans personne avec qui parler véritablement, {jusqu’à} {une panne} {dans le désert du Sahara}, {il y a six ans}. 
{Quelque chose} s’était cassé dans mon moteur. 
{Et comme} {je n’avais} avec moi ni mécanicien, ni passagers, {je me préparai} à {essayer de réussir}, {tout seul}, {une réparation difficile}. 
{C’était} pour moi {une question de vie ou de mort}. 
{J’avais} {à peine} {de l’eau à boire} pour huit jours.//
\glb
{Żyłem zatem} samemu, bez osoby z którą {rozmawia się} wiarygodnie {aż do} awarii {na pustyni Sahara} {6 lat temu} 
Coś było zepsute w moim silniku
{I jako że} {nie miałem} ze sobą ani mechanika ani pasażerów {przygotowałem się} do {spróbowania} samemu {ciężkiej naprawy}
{To była} dla mnie {kwestia życia i śmierci}
Miałem {zaledwie} {wody do picia} na osiem dni//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
{Le premier} soir {je me suis donc endormi} sur {le sable} {à mille milles} {de toute terre habitée}.
J’étais {bien plus} isolé qu’un naufragé sur {un radeau} au milieu {de l’océan}. 
Alors {vous imaginez} ma surprise, {au lever du jour}, quand {une drôle de petite voix} {m’a réveillé}. Elle {disait :…}//
\glb
Pierwszego wieczoru {zatem zasnąłem} na piasku {tysiące mil} {od ziemii zamieszkałej}
Byłem {dużo bardziej} odizolowony niż rozbitek na tratwie po środku oceanu
Więc {wyobrażacie sobie} moje zaskoczenie {o świcie} kiedy {zabawny głosik} {mnie obudził}.
On mówił//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— {S’il vous plaît…} dessine-moi {un mouton !} //
\glb
{} Proszę {narysuj mi} baranka//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— {Hein !} //
\glb
{} Co//
\endgl


\begingl
\gla
— Dessine-moi {un mouton}…//
\glb
{} {Narysuj mi} baranka//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
{J’ai sauté sur mes pieds} {comme si} {j’avais été} frappé par {la foudre}. 
{J’ai bien frotté} mes yeux. 
{J’ai bien regardé}. 
Et {j’ai vu} {un petit bonhomme} {tout à fait} extraordinaire qui {me considérait} gravement. 
Voilà {le meilleur} portrait que, {plus tard}, {j’ai réussi à faire de lui}.//
\glb
{Skoczyłem na równe nogi} jakbym był trafionym przez piorun
Przetarłem moje oczy. 
{Dobrze się przyjrzałem}. 
I widziałem {małego gościa} zupełnie nadzwyczajnego który {przyglądał mi się} poważnie 
Oto najlepszy portret który później {udało mi się jemu zrobić}//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
Mais mon dessin, {bien sûr}, est beaucoup moins ravissant que {le modèle}. 
Ce {n’est pas de ma faute}. 
{J’avais été} découragé dans ma carrière {de peintre} par {les grandes personnes}, {à l’âge de six ans}, et {je n’avais rien appris} {à dessiner}, sauf {les boas} fermés et {les boas} ouverts.//
\glb
Ale mój rysunek oczywiście jest dużo mniej wspaniały niż model
To {nie jest moja wina}
Byłem zniechęcony w mojej karierze malarza przez {dorosłe osoby} {w wieku 6 lat} i {nie nauczyłem się nic} rysować poza boza zamkniętymi i boa otwartymi//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
{Je regardai} donc cette apparition avec {des yeux} tout {ronds d’étonnement}.
{N’oubliez pas} que {je me trouvais} {à mille milles} {de toute région habitée}. 
Or mon petit bonhomme {ne me semblait} ni égaré, ni {mort de fatigue}, ni {mort de faim}, ni {mort de soif}, ni {mort de peur}. 
Il {n’avait} {en rien} l’apparence {d’un enfant} perdu {au milieu} {du désert}, {à mille milles} {de toute région habitée}. 
Quand {je réussis} enfin {à parler}, {je lui dis :}//
\glb
{Przyglądałem się} zatem tej zjawie z oczami całymi {zaokrąglonymi ze zdziwienia}
{Nie zapomnijcie} że {znalazłem się} {tysiące mil} {od regionu zamieszkałych}
Otóż mój mały gość {nie wydawał się} ani zgubiony ani zmęczony ani wygłodzony ani spragniony ani przestraszony.
On {nie miał} {w ogóle} wyglądu dziecka zgubionego {po środku} pustyni {tysiące mil} {od regionu zamieszkałego}
Kiedy {udało mi się} wreszcie odezwać, {powiedziałem mu}//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— Mais {qu’est-ce que} tu fais là//
\glb
{} Ale {co} ty robisz tutaj//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
Et {il me répéta} alors, {tout doucement}, comme {une chose} très {sérieuse :}//
\glb
I {powtórzył mi} wówczas powoli jakby rzecz bardzo ważną//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
— {S’il vous plaît…} dessine-moi {un mouton…}//
\glb
{} Proszę {narysuj mi} baranka//
\endgl

\begingl
\gla
Quand {le mystère} est trop impressionnant, {on n’ose pas désobéir}. 
Aussi absurde que cela {me semblât} {à mille milles} {de tous} {les endroits habités} et {en danger de mort}, {je sortis} {de ma poche} {une feuille de papier} et {un stylographe}. 
Mais {je me rappelai} {alors que} {j’avais surtout étudié} {la géographie}, l’histoire, {le calcul} et {la grammaire} et {je dis} {au petit bonhomme} (avec {un peu} {de mauvaise humeur}) que {je ne savais pas} dessiner. 
Il me {répondit :}//
\glb
Kiedy tajemnica jest zbyt imponująca {nie można odważyć się sprzeciwić} 
Również absurdalnie że tutaj {mnie wydawało się} {tysiące mil} {od wszystkich} {miejsc zamieszkałych} i {w niebezpieczeństwie śmierci} wyjąłem {z kieszieni} {kartkę papieru} i {wieczne pióro}
Ale {przypominałem sobie} {w tym samym momencie że} {studiowałem głównie} geografię, historię, rachunkowość i gramatykę i powiedziałem {małemu gościowi} (z trochę {złym humorem}) że {nie umiem} rysować
On mi odpowiedział//
\(\)\endgl


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great. I didn't know about `showframe` package, seems really helpful.